# How do you get the range of the x-axis of a Plotly graph?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to retrieve the range of the x-axis when you zoom in a plotly scatter plot, but when I tried to access it using:
    figure['layout']['xaxis']['range']
it just returns 'None'.

This is the code that I am using to create the graph:

```
# self.plot contains the dataframe passed to the function to be plotted
self.plot = df
# Creates the plotly plot figure
self.fig = self.plot.iplot(asFigure=True,kind='scatter', xTitle='Date', yTitle='Temperature')
# Displays the plot
iplot(self.fig, show_link=False)
```

I'm using cufflinks to create the plot from a pandas DataFrame so I don't explicitly set the layout.xaxis.range to anything. Also I'm using a Jupyter Notebook to display the graph, if that helps at all. So is there any way of getting the range of the x-axis of the current view window of the plot? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

That does not seem to be possible at the moment using python. There's a post on [community.plot.ly](https://community.plot.ly/t/retrieving-the-range-of-the-x-axis-of-a-zoomed-in-plot/1335) that says:

> Graph parameters don’t dynamically change with chart actions. However,
>   as you zoom, the plot does emit data regarding the new x-axis range,
>   you’re unable to to access this information directly in Python.
>   Instead you’d have to use javascript:
>   https://plot.ly/javascript/zoom-events/